# Simulating timeout on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

**Problem:**

I need to create a web project with a controller that times out.

**What I have done:**

- Create a new web application
- Empty the web.config, and write the values below:

.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1" />
        <compilation debug="false" />
        <httpModules>
            <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

- Write the following code to the controller:

.

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    public EmptyResult Index()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Response.Write("ScriptTimeout: " + HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout);
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

When run, the server sleeps for 3 seconds, then returns the response without any timeout error. ScriptTimeout value is 1.

**Question:**

Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a `408 Request Timeout` HTTP status code?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(408);
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: No, not really. Based on the example above, I want to make a one second timeout page/site.

Answer (score 1):

The `executionTimeout` attribute on the `<httpRuntime/>` element is only taken into account if `debug="false"` on the `<compilation/>` element.

Try removing the debug attribute or explicitly setting it to false. Of course, you'll have to run your application without debugging to test it.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx for more details.